# Can you help me with this 301 Redirect Regex code that has multiple 301 redirects? Will this be evaluated in order?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm working to combine a bunch of blogs on just one domain.  Most of the blogs have an easy 301 redirect of the whole site since the WordPress permalinks are all the same.  However, one of them has the author at the start of the permalink.  So, I'm trying to figure out how to get the domain with the author to do a 301 redirect on all the post pages.

Here's the permalink structure on the old and the new domain:

```
/%author%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

Example URL:

```
https://www.olddomain.com/guest/2018/12/05/battling-the-barriers-in-ep-cath-labs/

/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

Example New URL:

```
https://www.newdomain.com/2018/12/05/battling-the-barriers-in-ep-cath-labs/
```

I think I need to create a 301 redirect for each author like this:

```
#301 Redirect individual authors from olddomain.com to newdomain.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^guest/(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^stevie/(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1? [L,R=301]
```

And then I think I need to redirect everything else on the domain (tags, categories, author, homepage)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Does this code look like it will work to forward all the individual post pages and the rest of the domain?  Will the .htaccess file read the first redirects and do the redirect, but if it doesn't match will it keep going through the list of redirects until the last one which should catch everything?

Answer (score 0):

I found this really great website where you can put your .htaccess code and then test where your redirects are going: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/  It even shows what's getting processed.  It answered my question about which is that it works!